# Initializing an array inside a structure from another array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

```
struct sample {
    int x;
    int y;
    int arr[10];
};

int arr2[10] = {0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5};

int a = 19; 
int b = 22;
struct sample* samp = new sample;
samp->x = a;
samp->y = b;
samp->arr = ??
```

In the above example, I need to initialize array inside the structure **arr[10]** with the elements of **arr2[10]**.

How to do it in C++??

Comment: Stop using raw arrays and start using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Just in case you didn't take the precedent advice seriously. If you want to do C++, use std::vector, and the standard library containers in general.

Comment: change your **sample->** to **samp->**. **sample** is tag name and cant be used like that.

Comment: @Koushik: Fun fact: it can. `sample * sample = new struct sample; sample->x = ....;`. But yes, one should refrain from naming variables the same as classes.

Comment: @Zeta i was not referring to whether sample can be used like that or not what i meant was he had declared as sample * samp so here he should use samp and not sample. here in this code sample is just the tag name:-)

Comment: @Koushik: Yes, I noticed, that's why I called it a "fun fact" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to do it in C++??

The simplest solution is to use `std::copy` as was said by others. Do *not* use `memcpy` in C++, as `std::copy` does the same for PODs but also is applicable for non-PODs and just Does The Right Thing. If the type in your array changes one day, you would have to revisit all places where you do such a copy and replace the `memcpy`. (And you *will* miss one of the places and have a hard time to find the bug). Using `memcpy` in C++ has no benefits, so use `std::copy` from the start.

The better solution would be to **use C++ data structures**, in this case, use `std::array`

```
#include <array>
struct sample {
      int x;
      int y;
      std::array<int, 10> arr; //C++ array instead of plain C array
    };

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> arr2 = {0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5};

    int a = 19; 
    int b = 22;

    // 1: no need to say "struct sample*" since C++98
    // 2: prefer to use smart pointers..
    //sample* samp = new sample; 
    std::unique_ptr<sample> samp(new sample());
    samp->x = a;
    samp->y = b;
    samp->arr = arr2; //it's as easy as it should be!

    // 3: ... so ypu can't forget to delete!
    //delete samp;
}
```

**Edit:**
I used unique_ptr here, although in this little example you don't need to use heap allocation at all. To bring in Grijesh's initialization in as well:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> arr2 = {0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5};

    int a = 19; 
    int b = 22;

    sample samp = {a, b, arr2}; //done!
}
```

no allocation, no cleanup, no element-wise assignment needed.

Comment: ok this is your `std::array` good :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use memcpy:

```
memcpy(sample->arr,arr2,sizeof(int) * 10)
```

But I would suggest using std::vector for both.

Comment: you need: `10 * sizeof(int)`

Comment: @hannes yes, you are totally correct.

Comment: prefer `std::copy` over `memcpy` so you don't have to come back if the type changes to non-POD `MyIntType`. And vector is dynamic allocation, you don't need that if you know the size and it does not change - `std::array` is the better container for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Copy array using for loop,

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    samp->arr[i]=arr2[i];
}
```

Comment: why use handwritten loops if algorithm can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Usually one would use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) (`<algorithm>`) for this:

```
std::copy(std::begin(arr2), std::end(arr2), std::begin(samp->arr));
```

Note that [`std::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) (`<iterator>`) need C++11 support. If your compiler doesn't support C++11 you can provide this functions quite easily yourself or use pointer arithmetics:

```
std::copy(arr2, arr2 + 10, samp->arr);
```

That being sad, you should try to use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays or `std::array` (c++11) for fixed size arrays.