# Initializing array in struct

Tags: c++, templates, initialization

Assume we have some templated struct and *sometimes* it's template should be an array. How to initialize array in struct?

This

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    T x;
    A(T x) : x(x) {}
};


int a[6];
A<decltype(a)> b(a);
```

generates error during compilation:

```
error: array initializer must be an initializer list
A(T x) : x(x) {}
         ^
```

**UPD1.** More complete code this thing is used in:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    T x;
    A(const T& x) : x(x) {}
    A(const T&& x) : x(std::move(x)) {}
};

template<typename T>
A<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type> make_A(T&& a) {
    return A<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(a));
}


auto a = make_A("abacaba");
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use `std::array<>` instead of C-arrays?

Comment: `auto a = "abacaba"` is the reason

Comment: Couldn't you juast add a c'tor for an initializer list?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220126/initializing-an-array-inside-a-structure-from-another-array-in-c)?

Comment: @J.S. : Fair enough! How about, rather than using `A<decltype(x)>`, a `make_A`-style function that can be overloaded to return an `A<T>` normally and an `A<array<T, N>>` given a `T[N]`?

Comment: Looks like you have to specialize it anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing an array inside a structure from another array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220126/initializing-an-array-inside-a-structure-from-another-array-in-c)

Comment: @liliscent It's not really a duplicate. The template question adds something to it.

Comment: @ildjarn see upd1

Comment: @J.S., the two code blocks have different errors

Comment: @codekaizer not really, the second example shows `error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal` (`or string literal` added), if we use `int a[6]; auto b = make_A(a);` then we'll get exactly same error

Comment: @J.S, `A<decltype(a)&> b(a)`

Comment: @codekaizer but if `a` is `int` for example it's bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general solution is to provide a special constructor for arrays (enabled when `T` is an array) which copies the source array to the struct's array. It works, but discard move semantics for arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    using value_type = std::remove_const_t<T>;
    value_type x;

    template<class U=T> A(const T&  src, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_array_v<U>, int> = 0) : x(src) {}
    template<class U=T> A(const T&& src, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_array_v<U>, int> = 0) : x(std::move(src)) {}
    template<class U=T> A(const T&  src, std::enable_if_t< std::is_array_v<U>, int> = 0) { std::copy(std::begin(src), std::end(src), std::begin(x)); }
};

template<typename T>
auto make_A(T&& a)
{ return A<typename std::remove_reference_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(a)); }

int main()
{
    auto a1 = make_A("the answer");
    std::ignore = a1;
    auto a2 = make_A(42);
    std::ignore = a2;
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/399de61af742394d)

If you need `T` to be `const` for non-arrays sometimes, an improvement would be to define `value_type` as `T` if `T` is not an array and to `std::remove_const_t<T>` otherwise.

Comment: that's probably the only solution that doesn't have strange behaviour...

Comment: @Swift : What do you mean..?

Comment: @ildjarn other way would either change semantics of initial question (we *have* to store array, not a pointer or a class) or how to use it. it might be important for OP, MCVS would not tell us that information

Answer (score 1):

I suggest putting all the smarts into `make_A`, converting C-arrays to `std::array<>`s so that `A<>` needs only work with regular types:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename T, std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> to_std_array(T const* const p,
                                                        std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return {{p[Is]...}};
    }
}

template<typename T>
A<std::decay_t<T>> make_A(T&& x) {
    return {std::forward<T>(x)};
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
A<std::array<T, N>> make_A(T const (& x)[N]) {
    return {detail::to_std_array(x, std::make_index_sequence<N>{})};
}
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fbdf6bb8a999267)**</kbd>

If you're only concerned with hardcoded C-strings in particular (as opposed to C-arrays in general), consider converting to a `string_view` type rather than `std::array<>` to potentially save some space.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a special behaviour you want to achieve for C-Strings exclusively, you may just add a special treatment:

```
// for all non-C-string cases
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, const char*>>* = nullptr>
A<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type> make_A(T&& a) {
    return A<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(a));
}

// in case a C-string got passed
A<std::string> make_A(const std::string& str) {
    return A<std::string>(str);
}

int main()
{
    auto a = make_A("abacaba");
    auto b = make_A(5);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With *std::decay* it works:

```
template<typename T>
A<typename std::decay<T>::type> make_A(T&& a) {
    return A<typename std::decay<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(a));
}
```

Comment: T is now `char const *`, hardly an "array in struct"

Comment: @KillzoneKid, yep, but it is really like an array and still(?) default thing to work with strings